# shutil returns IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ioerror, shutil

I am trying to copy text file from one folder to another using shutil in python. i wrote the following lines:

```
import shutil
path_to_text= 'C:\pyprog\sample.txt'
dest = 'C:\pyprog\dest'
```

But every time I call this code I get Errno 2. The traceback for the error is

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 88, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\pyprog\\sample.txt'`

The file exists so probably I'm doing something wrong. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Make sure your file isn't called `sample.txt.txt`. Windows likes to do that.

Comment: evil windows. You were right. thanks.

Comment: but now I'm getting `{IOERROR}[errno 13] permission denied:\\pyprog`

Comment: If you are using anything newer than Windows XP, you will probably need to run your script as Administrator as most folders directly under the C: drive are locked down. If you want a good place to read/write files from, I would recommend your "My Documents" folder or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Not

```
shutil.copyfile(dst, src)
```